# A book about stopping time

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

When I was younger like in 7th grade or something, about 6 years ago, I remember I picked up this book that was about time stopping. I don’t know if it was a series or a single book. I don’t remember the name or the author, except that I’m pretty sure his name was James but I’m not sure, but I do remember this:

It was about how two teens, boy and girl,  (around 14 or 16) who were the only ones unaffected when the world and everyone in it stopped. There was a bad guy who I think was like from history. They teamed up to try and stop the evil guy and became friends. I think also along the way they found a group of “rogue kids” who were also unaffected.  And I also remember the name of the girl which was Cassie and I’m not entirely sure but I think the boy’s name was Jack or something along the lines.

Comment: When you say you’ve  been looking for it for years and you were in 7th grade do you roughly know how long ago that was? Do you know why time stopped? Why they were unaffected? If you remember anything else you can [edit] your post to include it.

Comment: That was about 6 years ago and I don’t remember anything except what I mentioned

Comment: *[The Midnighters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnighters_trilogy)* has kids who can operate in stopped time, but the names don't match, and they oppose creatures.

Comment: Sort of a long shot: The first of the "Time Stoppers" books was published in 2016, and while the main character's name is not "Cassie", the author's first name is "Carrie." The book features a girl and boy named Annie and Jamie.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26073154-time-stoppers

Comment: @Bitterfiction: That looks like a good enough match to me to post as an answer!

Comment: That’s was really close but that wasn’t it. Thank you tho. I do now remember the cover very vaguely. It was of a blond girl and a black haired boy. And it was like they were running.

Comment: Oh this could be one of the Mind Dimension books by Dima Zales! First one is "The Thought Readers", check it out here: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23378951-the-thought-readers?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=7UeDKATIDN&rank=2

Answer (score 9):

The first of the "Time Stoppers" books was published in 2016, and while the main character's name is not "Cassie", the author's name is Carrie Jones.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26073154-time-stoppers

The book features a girl and boy named Annie and Jamie:

> "Annie Nobody thought she was, well, nobody, living in a nowhere town
> where nothing goes her way. Day 1 at her newest foster home proves to
> be dreadful, too... and things get even worse when she's chased by
> something big and scary that definitely wants to eat her.
>
> Luckily for Annie, not everything is what it seems, and she gets swept
> up-literally-by a sassy dwarf on a hovercraft snowmobile and taken to
> Aurora, a hidden, magical town on the coast of Maine. There, she finds
> a new best friend in Jamie Hephastion Alexander--who thought he was a
> normal kid (but just might be a troll)-and Annie discovers that she's
> not exactly who she thought she was, either. She's a Time Stopper,
> meant to protect the enchanted.
>
> Together, Annie and Jamie discover a whole new world of magic, power,
> and an incredible cast of creatures and characters. But where there's
> great power, there are also those who want to misuse it, and Aurora is
> under siege. It's up to the kids to protect their new home, even if it
> means diving headfirst into magical danger."